# Bootstrap design is not rendering on page when @Html.ActionLink is passed with parameter.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

When i use Html.ActionLink without parameter values the destination view's bootstrap loads normally but when I try to pass pa parameter the destination view's bootstrap does not load it only displays simple html without bootstrap. I'm using sb-admin-2 btw.

I have already tried all the method overloading of @Html.ActionLink but nothing works.

When you click this link the page load and data are passed but the bootstrap fails to load.

@Html.Actionlink with parameter code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "AddOrEdit", "Receiving", new { @id = item.ReceivingDocumentNo }, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-info" })
```

@Html.ActionLink without parameter code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "AddOrEdit", "Receiving", new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Please refer to this link to the image results of the views. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKwib.jpg

Controller Code:

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult AddOrEdit(string id = "")
        {

            List<DTS.Models.DocumentType> documentTypeList = new List<DocumentType>();
            List<Section> sectionList = new List<Section>();
            documentTypeList = DapperORM.ReturnList<DocumentType>("ViewAllDocumentTypesReceiving").ToList<DocumentType>();
            sectionList = DapperORM.ReturnList<Section>("ViewAllSections").ToList<Section>();

            ViewData["DocumentTypeList"] = documentTypeList;
            ViewData["SectionList"] = sectionList;


            Receiving res = new Receiving();
            if (id == "")
            {
                res.ReceivingDocumentNo = DapperORM.ReturnList<string>("GenerateReceivingTrackingNo", null).FirstOrDefault<string>();
                res.ReceivingSections = sectionList;
            }
            else
            {
                DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@ReceivingDocumentNo", id);
                res = DapperORM.ReturnList<Receiving>("GetReceivingDetailsForUpdateByReceivingDocumentNo", param).FirstOrDefault<Receiving>();
                res.ReceivingSections = DapperORM.ReturnList<Section>("GetReceivingListForUpdateByDocumentNo", param).ToList<Section>();


            }

            return View(res);
        }
```

The result should be the same with the bootstrap layout rendering normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your _Layout.cshtml being applied at all?  I do believe the problem is not in the submitted code but rather in the view code, and that the information provided is not enough to get a specific answer. -regards.

Comment: Thank you sir found the issue on my _Layout.cshtml